# Accordion onchange function is not taking current value using material-ui in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, accordion

I am using @material-ui Accordion, the onChange function is not taking current value. Ex - when i am clicking on panel1 icon then its opening panel2 its not taking current value on icon click. I am sharing panel1 code? Am i missing something here?

```
const handleAccordionChange = (panel) => (event, newExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(newExpanded ? panel : false);
  };

 <Accordion
              expanded={expanded === 'panel1'}
              onChange={handleAccordionChange('panel1')}
              classes={{
                root: classes.MuiAccordionroot
              }}
            >
              <AccordionSummary
                className="accrdSummary"
                expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                id="panel1a-header"
                classes={{ expandIcon: classes.MuiAccordionSummaryIcon }}
              >
                <Typography><div id="deployment" style={{ fontSize: "14px", fontWeight: "600" }}>Deploy</div></Typography>
              </AccordionSummary>
              <AccordionDetails className="accrdDetails">
                <CreateButton
                  id="addEnvironmentButton"
                  variant="outlined"
                  startIcon={<AddIcon />}
                  className="envButtons"
                  onClick={addHandeler}
                >
                  Add Environment
                </CreateButton>
                <br />
                {environmentVar.map((element, index) => (
                  <Environment
                    onChangeEnv={changeEnv}
                    environmentVar={element}
                    index={index}
                    deleteHandeler={() => deleteHandeler(index)}
                  />
                ))}
              </AccordionDetails>
            </Accordion>
```

Can somebody please help on same?

I am trying to pass different id, name to each accordion but this din't work out. In event.target i don't see name, ids.

Comment: Where's the code for `handleAccordionChange`?

Comment: I have added in same code block.

Comment: I made [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-banzai-uc579i?file=/demo.tsx) and it seems to be working just fine. Could you be more specific about your issue?

Comment: Could it be possible to give name or id to accordion?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of MUI Accordian https://codesandbox.io/s/qgk40c?file=/demo.tsx

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState<string | false>(false);

  const handleChange =
    (panel: string) => (event: React.SyntheticEvent, isExpanded: boolean) => {
      setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
    };
```

Your code looks fine to me.

The above shared example was taken from MUI https://mui.com/material-ui/react-accordion/#controlled-accordion

Comment: I don't know what is wrong in my code, i know the code looks fine but on iconClick this is the issue is occurring and for the label click it is working fine. That is why i am posting here if somebody faced this kind of issue.